# Multiple worksheet_change with same macro with different reference cell

Tags: vba, excel

Want to create some dynamic dashboard in which the shapes will alter color as the reference cell's value would change (based on some threshold value).

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("M5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
        If Target.Value < Range("$AA$5") Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 3").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        ElseIf Target.Value >= Range("$AA$5") And Target.Value < Range("$Y$5") Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 3").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        ElseIf Target.Value >= Range("$Y$5") And Target.Value < Range("$Z$5") Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 3").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
        ElseIf Target.Value >= Range("$Z$5") And Target.Value < Range("$AB$5") Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 3").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 3").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        End If
    End If   

End Sub
```

This is working fine for one Triangle in the Dashboard with some defined threshold value (changing color dynamically). Want replicate the same operation with other triangles as well. How that can be done?

[![The sequence of Triangles][1]][1]

***Edited & Added part:***

The dashboard has multiple Brand wise performance to showcase.

The schematic diagram:[enter image description here][2]

The Actual data across brands at CFA, DB & SS level :
Actual Data 
[enter image description here][3]

The threshold level across CFA, SS & Sub D:
[enter image description here][4]

So for every brand (Brand 1,2 &3) at stocking points (CFA,DB & SS level), the color code behave like:

```
If the actual< UCL2, the triangle will be red (e.g. Brand1 at CFA is 9, respective tringle will be red), UCL2<= actual Yellow , UCL1<= actual Green , LCL1<= actual Yellow , Actual =>LCL2 --> Red
```

Hope now the problem is much more crystal. Anticipating assistance regarding this...TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED on your request**

and sligthly refactored

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     Colorize ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 1"), Target, Range, ("M1"), Range("$AA$5").Value, Range("$AB$5").Value, Range("$Y$5").Value, Range("$Z$5").Value
     Colorize ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 2"), Target, Range("M3"), 19, 60, 32, 38
     'Colorize ActiveSheet.Shapes("Isosceles Triangle 3"), Target, Range("M5")

End Sub

Private Sub Colorize(shp As Shape, ByVal Target As Range, rValue as Range, _
     YellowLow As long, YellowHigh As Long, _
     GreenLow As Long, GreenHigh As Long)

     Dim iColor As Long

     If Intersect(Target, rValue) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

     'If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
     '    iColor = vbRed
     '    If Target.Value < Range("$AA$5") Then
     '        iColor = vbRed
     '    ElseIf Target.Value >= Range("$AA$5") And Target.Value < Range("$Y$5") Then
     '        iColor = vbYellow
     '    ElseIf Target.Value >= Range("$Y$5") And Target.Value < Range("$Z$5") Then
     '        iColor = vbGreen
     '    ElseIf Target.Value >= Range("$Z$5") And Target.Value < Range("$AB$5") Then
     '        iColor = vbYellow
     '    End If
     If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
         iColor = vbRed
         If Target.Value >= YellowLow And Target.Value <= YellowHigh Then  iColor = vbYellow
         If Target.Value >= GreenLow And Target.Value <= GreenHigh Then    iColor = vbGreen
         shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = iColor
    End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply .. it's working fine when the same conditions are applied for these 3 shapes...Could you please suggest how to incorporate this when these 3 shapes will follow different criteria...say, Triangle 1 will indicate Green in the range (19 to 25), whereas Triangle 2 will indicate   Green in the range (15 to 20)...Please suggest.

Comment: Tried to put the problem in much more detailed manner...Could you please have a look and let me know how to address the stuff

Comment: I can't see the pictures.

Comment: It's not allowing images to be posted from my profile it seems ...is there any other means I can share these ...please suggest